# Speeding up minimization problem related to a minimal surface

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, geometry, variational-calculus

I am trying to find the minimum of the function $$f(x)=\int_0^1(1+t^x)\sqrt{1+x^2 t^{2(x-1)}}dt$$ which arises from trying to minimize the surface area of a function rotated around the $x$ axis. Here I am letting that function be equal to $1+t^x$ to obtain an upper bound on the minimum value. Anyway, I used

```
FindMinimum[ Integrate[(1 + t^x)(1 + x^2 t^(2(x - 1)))^(1/2), {t,0,1}], {x,0,10}]
```

to find the minimum, and it just kept loading. Is it possible to make it easier for *Mathematica* to compute it quicker? I have only started to use *Mathematica* a few days ago and not regularly, so please avoid any "jargon" in your answer.

Edit: After checking *Mathematica* it says:

[image]

This is not true because $f(0)=2$.

Apparently it is lagging this hard?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Does this integral evaluate to a function?

Comment: @Syed Yes, notice that we are integrating with respect to $t$ and not $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculating the integral without any assumptions we obtain a `ConditionalExpression` which may not work quite seamlessly with `FindMinimum`.  When we tackle an involved analytic expression and we expect that it takes a while to find a symbolic integral  and a natural remedy might be a numeric definition of the function.

**Numeric definition**

```
fn[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1 + t^x) (1 + x^2 t^(2 (x - 1)))^(1/2), {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[ fn[x], {x, 0.1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

and one can find the minimum, e.g.

```
FindMinimum[ fn[x], {x, 0.1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {2.08127, {x -> 1.65739}}
> ```

**Symbolic definition**

We can also calculate the integral analytically, however it takes a minute or so, but one shouldn't expect much faster processing when  hypergeometric functions are involved. We define a piecewise function:

```
fi[x_, a_] := Integrate[(1 + t^x) (1 + x^2 t^(2 (x - 1)))^(1/2), {t, 0, 1}, 
                Assumptions -> a]
f[x_] = Piecewise @ Table[{fi[x, a], a}, {a, {0 < x < 1, x == 1, x > 1}}];
f[x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and now we can find the maximum e.g.

```
NMinimize[{f[x], 1 < x < 3}, x]
```

> ```
> {2.08127, {x -> 1.65739}}
> ```

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{1.65739, 2.08127}]}]
```

[image]

Sometimes one could also find a symbolic expression for the minimum but this is a different story which cannot be always successful especially when hypergeometric functions are involved.

**Surface**

```
RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0.01, 3}, Exclusions -> x == 1.65739, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 30], Opacity[0.3]],
  RevolutionAxis -> { 1, 0, 0}, Mesh -> {6, 15}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Darker@Cyan}]
```

[image]

Comment: That’s what I got through Desmos as well. So the moral here is if Mathematica can’t integrate then we make it analytically integrate?

Comment: We should take a chance to calculate a numeric integral instead of symbolic one when we expect an immediate result.  Analytic expressions are worthy but also expensive.